# Magento 2 checkout session get empty data after payment success in success.phtml file

Tags: magento2, checkout, customer-session, chrome-browser, checkoutsession

Magento 2 Customer logged out automatically after  checkout process..After payment gateway from third party, customer logout automatically in chrome browser..It work fine in mozilaa browser.

Comment: Are you using hosted payment page which redirect user to third party website? If yes then please follow native Magneto PayPal express checkout code to know how to solve this.

Comment: $checkout_session = $objectManager->get('Magento\Checkout\Model\Session');
$order = $checkout_session->getLastRealOrder();
$order is empty in sucess.phtml

Comment: Customer should logout from browser. Some issue in your code level

Answer (score 0):

I had exactly the same issue: customers were being logged out after the checkout process (usually new registered customers. We had a custom module to let them sign up directly in checkout: Firecheckout). Your case might be different, but I'll hope this can help you:

Check your new order email templates. Have you added any custom blocks using the {{block ...}} syntax? If so, try removing them and check if the issue still persists.

The explanation is the following (if it's your case): when including blocks of this type in email templates, all the load_layout_before observers will be called. The load_layout_before observers end up calling the function checkIfDepersonalize in vendor/magento/module-page-cache/Model/DepersonalizeChecker.php.

If it returns 'yes', then your customer session data will be removed, and it will be logged out.

That said: if the origin of the problem is not the same as mine, you can anyway analyze that class, check whether it's returning true and debug.

Check also this Atwix post about session depersonalization:
https://www.atwix.com/magento-2/session-depersonalization-in-magento-2-why-and-how/

And you can also read about my debugging nightmare on the same issue: https://campus.m.academy/c/debugging-help/xdebug-stop-when-expression-value-changes

Comment: $checkout_session = $objectManager->get('Magento\Checkout\Model\Session'); $order = $checkout_session->getLastRealOrder(); $order is empty in sucess.phtml

Comment: You're not looking at the right direction. Your customer has been logged out before getting to the success page. That's why you get $order = empty. You need to find out what's logging out your customer. Have you checked your email templates?

Comment: How do I know what's logging out the customer?How to check ? The problem is on chrome browser.It working fine in mozilla.